# How to correctly use git with ROS

Tags: ros, best-practices, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

We are beginning building a stack in ros. And we want to use git as our version control system. But we find a lot of problems with conflicted files created by ROS when we build the packages.

To solve this kind of problems you have done a big .gitignore file ? Or do something to   build the project outsite ?

Thanks for all your answers,

Arnau

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10182/how-to-correctly-use-git-with-ros/) by [Catotaku](https://answers.ros.org/users/516/catotaku/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2011-06-06

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-11-20**:
Good question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In our repository, we have a `.gitignore` file with the following contents:

```
.cproject
.project
.pydevproject
cmake_install.cmake
build/
bin/
lib/
msg_gen/
srv_gen/
```

(The first three lines are only relevant if you are using Eclipse.) By placing this file in the top-level directory of the repository, git will ignore all those files/folders even in all subdirectories.

This way, I only need a separate `.gitignore` file in a package directory to catch some special cases. One not-so-special "special case" is when you have an action definition (e.g., `JointMovement` in the package `katana`). In that case, I have the following `.gitignore`:

```
msg/JointMovementActionFeedback.msg
msg/JointMovementActionGoal.msg
msg/JointMovementAction.msg
msg/JointMovementActionResult.msg
msg/JointMovementFeedback.msg
msg/JointMovementGoal.msg
msg/JointMovementResult.msg
src/katana/
msg/lisp/
```

Unfortunately, I have not found a decent way yet to include these patterns into the global `.gitignore`.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-06-08**:
I think the msg/lisp is not needed anymore, at least for diamondback. Roslisp generates its messages into msg_gen now.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-07-29**:
Would the following work for actionlib-generated msgs in package FOO?

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-07-29**:
FOO/msg/*Action.msg
FOO/msg/*Feedback.msg
FOO/msg/*Goal.msg
FOO/msg/*Result.msg

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-07-29**:
(replace spaces with line breaks)

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-07-29**:
Yes, that works. Or borrowing from @"felix k"'s answer, you can also put `*/msg/*Action.msg` etc. into the parent directory. Just tried it [here](https://github.com/uos/katana_driver/commit/838af6197ea20ee16e90b815753a6058dcba0b6a).

NB: you can put line breaks into comments using shift-enter. :-)

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-07-29**:
Ooops. Seems like all the fancy markdown (and shift-enter trick) doesn't work any more in comments. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are using gut for most of our stacks. A common gitignore file contains the following entries:

```
build
bin
lib
msg_gen
srv_gen
```

You might also want to add generated python files that are placed in src/<your_package> for each package.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good rule of thumb is to do a `make clean` on your package before you check it in. Anything leftover after `make clean` is usually safe to include in a git repo.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like Martins list and would like to add *hidden backups* and *compiled python* files, as I put pythons in src/ rather than bin/ most times.

```
*~
*.pyc
```

---

To ignore headers generated into `<package>/src/<package>/.../` you can either put this in the package's .gitignore:

```
src/*/cfg
src/*/msg
src/*/srv
```

or this in the parent folder's .gitignore:

```
*/src/*/cfg
*/src/*/msg
*/src/*/srv
```

*Note that one level of stars denotes the parent folder, independent of that one being your repo base or metapackage folder.*

This does not yet ignore `<package>/src/<package>/__init__.py`, for which I suggest an specific entry in each package where needed.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To hide the files generated by dynamic reconfigure we also have this lines in our .gitignore:

```
*.cfgc
__init__.py
src/*/cfg
cfg/cpp
```

---

Originally posted by [Pascal](https://answers.ros.org/users/2358/pascal/) with karma: 76 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-11-22**:
All good additions, but the `__init__.py` is a little too general (you do want to check in some files with that name, only not those generated by dynamic reconfigure).

**Comment by [Neil Traft](https://answers.ros.org/users/17791/neil-traft/) on 2014-08-12**:
The cfg/cpp entry doesn't work for me. I've started a StackOverflow question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275635/gitignore-a-nested-directory-structure-anywhere-in-my-repository